# square matrix and secondary diagonal in java

Tags: java

I have this assignment:

Given a square matrix m[3x3], create a java code to calculate the value of its SECONDARY Diagonal. See example below.

Example given matrix m[3x3] shown below:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2)   |   10   12  11
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2)   |   9   8   31
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)   |   2   16  24
Secondary Diagonal (generic m[3x3]) = m[0,2] + m[1,1] + m[2,0]
Secondary Diagonal (as in the example above) = 11 + 8 + 2 = 21
```

Note 1: Your java code MUST be GENERIC to calculate the secondary diagonal of ANY square matrix [2x2], [3x3],[4x4], etc. (Use a constant in your code to set the values of numberOfRows and numberOfColumns of your matrix.

Note 2: Your matrix m may be hardcoded (no need of user interaction)

Note 3: In case numberOfRows and numberOfColumns are different, your program must display the following message: “This is not a square matrix.”

So far I have:

```
public class matrix {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] [] matrix = {
            { 10, 12, 11},
            {9, 8, 31},
            {2, 16, 24}
    };
    int secondaryDiagonal = 0;
    int size = matrix.length -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        secondaryDiagonal += matrix[i][size-i];
    }
    System.out.println("Secondary diagonal is " + secondaryDiagonal);


    }
}
```

It works, but I am not able to find a way to implement all the notes at the end... Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already achieved Requirements 1 and 2.

For 3, find the number of rows and columns and display a message and not do anything.

```
int numberOfRows = matrix.length;
int numberOfColumns = matrix[0].length; //Note must have atleast one row

if (numberOfRows != numberOfColumns) {
    System.out.println("This is not a square matrix");
} else {
  //proceed to find secondaryDiagonal
}
```

If passed an empty matrix (like `int [][] matrix = {};`), you need to decide what to do. In this case, `numberOfRows` will be 0. So, the second condition needs to be enhanced to handle this.

```
numberOfColumns = numberOfRows > 0 ? matrix[0].length : 0
```

The above will not report any message, instead will fall to the *else* block and will result in `Secondary diagonal is 0`.

It also assumes all rows have the same number of columns which I guess might be okay for you and don't need such extensive tests(from your notes)

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
public int[][] reflectAboutSecondaryDiagonal(int[][] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
            int temp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[n - 1 - j][n - 1 - i];
            a[n - 1 - j][n - 1 - i] = temp;
        }
    return a;
}
```